How to test react-native-auth0 library with detox?
I can't find a way anywhere that explains how to properly mock auth0 requests in React Native.
Several questions made on detox GitHub says that its not their responsibility to explain how to mock auth0, and I agree.
However I did not find a step by step explanation anywhere else - not even just the source code to look at.
Can someone please help?

My code has a button that on click calls auth0.webAuth.authorize


Show something to clarify your desire and what you have done! Otherwise we can't help you at all.

are you using webview for authentication ?

@ko100v.d Yes, I am using webview for authentication

It is not easy to test WebView components with Detox, If your app is opening an in-app browser it is almost impossible.
If you're using WebViewComponent there is a workaround. Basically you need to inject JavaScript that will populate the Username/Email and PasswordField and have a hidden button that will trigger the authentication.
        <View style={styles.fakeLoginButtonContainer}>
            <Button
                testID='e2e-login-test-id'
                title='DUMMY_LOGIN_BUTTON'
                onPress={() => {
                    console.log('hacking webview')
                    const jsCode =
                        "document.getElementById('signInName').value = '{USERNAME_EMAIL}';document.getElementById('password').value = '{PASSWORD}';document.getElementById('next').disabled = false;document.getElementById('next').click();"
                    webViewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(jsCode)
                }}
            />
         </View>

This workaround has worked for me in the past. Good Luck.
